# JavaScript Using RegEx to Parse LastName

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, names

I've seen lots of posts that are -almost- what I need and I've managed to get -almost- the answer I need, but I could use a little help getting the final bit. I think I'm getting confused between when to use .match and when to use .replace. (I may have seen the answer in other posts, but without the context of how to apply it, I didn't recognize it; it's the requirement for the hyphen that has made this interesting.)

I have an input textbox that looks like this --

```
<input type="text" id="PatientLastName"
                 name="PatientLastName"
               onblur="FormatLastName('PatientLastName')"
                value="@Model.PatientLastName"
            maxlength="100" required />
```

The onblur function is --

```
function FormatLastName(textBoxID) {
     var someName = document.getElementById(textBoxID).value.toUpperCase();
     someName = $.trim(someName);
     var reName = /(([A-Z])+((\-?)([A-Z]*)*))/;
     var matches = someName.match(reName);
     var aName = matches[1];
     document.getElementById(textBoxID).value = aName;
}
```

I need to be able to pull just the name parts out of any input -- for example,

```
9898s+m+_it????h-22324j4o5n4e0=s will give me SMITH-JONES
```

which is the desired output. (all uppper-case, the only special character allowed is one and only one hyphen between letters. A name like "O'Reilly" would become "OREILLY". No support for non-English characters, nor accents.)

And if there no hyphens, it works okay as well, for example

```
9898s+m+_it????h22324j4o5n4e0=s will give me SMITHJONES
```

But for --

```
9898s+m+_it????h-22324j4o5n4e0-=s will give me SMITH-
```

So I'm guessing I've got either the grouping or quantifiers not quite right; maybe I need to look at more matches? The script for first name is working fine, but it's based on .replace -- I couldn't find a way to get .replace to work with the hyphen.

The first name version works, using .replace, is --

```
function FormatFirstName(textBoxID) {
     var someName = document.getElementById(textBoxID).value.toUpperCase();
     someName = $.trim(someName);
     someName = someName.replace(/[^A-Z]/g, '');
     document.getElementById(textBoxID).value = someName;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

--edit-- I hope I haven't confused things by including the FirstName function. I put that in to show where I can get to where I need to be in terms of getting rid of special characters and uppercasing -- but it doesn't do the pattern matching I need. Replace looks like it could leave me with a trailing hyphen and doesn't seem to filter cases where there is more than one hyphen. I need SMITH-JONES, SMITH--JONES would be a problem, as would SMITH-.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: @Toto -- yes, that's a good checklist, but I'm recording patient names and they are happier with simplified names. Some of their systems are old and would break if you tried to enter other types of names. So even though developers know names can have an amazing array of variations, these end-users have simple needs. It's a case of giving the client what they ask for.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace in `onblur` function. I have created an example for you to look at

```js
function getValue(){
  var value= arguments[0];
  value = value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\-]*/g, "");
  console.log(value.toUpperCase());
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onblur="getValue(this.value)"/>
```

and in this particular case please update your function as

```
function FormatFirstName(textBoxID) {
     var someName = document.getElementById(textBoxID).value.toUpperCase();
     someName = $.trim(someName);
     someName = someName.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\-]*/g, ''); 
     document.getElementById(textBoxID).value = someName.toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: @Faroog -- thanks for providing an example of how "this." should be used, I'd been unclear on that. When I test that code using "smith--jones--" it returns "SMITH--JONES--" when I'm looking for "SMITH-JONES" A simple replace doesn't look like it can filter out multiple hyphens or prevent a trailing hyphen. Not a problem when parsing a first name, but doesn't work for last name.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like:

```
function FormatFirstName(textBoxID) {
    var someName = document.getElementById(textBoxID).value.toUpperCase();
    someName = $.trim(someName);
    someName = someName.replace(/[^A-Z\-]/g, '');
    document.getElementById(textBoxID).value = someName;
}
```

the `\-` in RegExp allows hyphens to be preserved.

Comment: Yes, I did see that as an option, but that doesn't prevent something like "SMITH-" where the hyphen is the last character and it doesn't look like it would prevent multiple hyphens like "SMITH-JONES-RENTY". replace seemed like a good approach for getting rid of the characters I didn't want, but haven't been able to figure out how to match the pattern for the name.

Comment: You can add `-$` in the RegExp to avoid ending hyphens. But I don't see any easy solution for "double hyphens". Except something ugly like `someName.replace(/[^A-Z\-]|-$/g, '').replace(/--/g,'-');`

Comment: Can you also explain me what do you wan't to get when input is "SMITH-JONES-RENTY" ?

Comment: Correction : use `someName.replace(/[^A-Z\-]|-*$/g, '').replace(/--/g,'-');` to replace all ending glyphens like "SMITH----"